# Finding CDF for simulation

Tags: probability, statistics

I have the following pdf:

$f(x) = 2\alpha e^{-\alpha x} (1 - e^{-\alpha x})$, $x>0, \alpha>0$ fixed.

I need to find the cdf to simulate X.

$$F(x)=  \int_{-\infty}^{x}(2\alpha\cdot e^{-\alpha\cdot t})dt= \left ( 1-e^{-\alpha\cdot t} \right )^{2}-\displaystyle \lim_{t \to -\infty} ( 1-e^{-\alpha\cdot t})^{2} = (1-e^{-\alpha\cdot t})^{2}\cdot (1-e^{\infty})^{2} = -\infty$$ Why isn't it finite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The random variable $X$ is positive by assumption, but you took the whole real line for the domain when computing its CDF. Instead, you should have had :
$$
F_X(x) = \left.\int_\color{red}{0}^x 2\alpha e^{-\alpha t} (1 - e^{-\alpha t}) \,\mathrm{d}t = (1 - e^{-\alpha t})^2\right|_0^x = (1 - e^{-\alpha x})^2
$$

Comment: Is it always positive?

Comment: @Student  You wrote it yourself at the beginning : $x > 0$.

Comment: So the integral when $x < 0 $ would be $0$. I understand. Thank you!

Comment: @Student  You're welcome ;)